# How to pull data from Google Sheets to HTML table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, template-engine

I'm trying to adapt this model. It is an HTML table that retrieves data from a Google table. However, I need the search to be done in a specific column. In this model, the search is performed in any column.
I've tried a few options, but to no avail. I believe it is necessary to change the function search  or the function createTable.
This is my code:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(formObject.searchtext);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRage        = 'Data!A2:Y';                                    //** CHANGE !!!
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        <script>
          //PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
          function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
              forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true); 
             
          
          //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
            document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
          }
        
          //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
          function createTable(dataArray) {
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                             "<tr>"+                               //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                              "<th scope='col'>ORDERNUMBER</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>QUANTITYORDERED</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>PRICEEACH</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>ORDERLINENUMBER</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>SALES</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>ORDERDATE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>STATUS</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>QTR_ID</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>MONTH_ID</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>YEAR_ID</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>PRODUCTLINE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>MSRP</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>PRODUCTCODE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>CUSTOMERNAME</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>PHONE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>ADDRESSLINE1</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>ADDRESSLINE2</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>CITY</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>STATE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>POSTALCODE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>COUNTRY</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>TERRITORY</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>CONTACTLASTNAME</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>CONTACTFIRSTNAME</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>DEALSIZE</th>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                          "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
              result += "</table>";
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = result;
            }else{
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              //div.empty()
              div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
            }
          }
        </script>
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ~ END ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                      <label for="searchtext">CPF</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" placeholder="Digite seu CPF">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Pesquisar</button>
                  </form>
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END ------------------------------------------- -->
              
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------------ -->
                <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">
                  <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
                </div>
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a html template that calls a function that returns a 2D array from a spreadsheet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabledata">
       <? var vs = lfunko ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```